# UNITY 2022.1.23 Gradle build failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

C:\Users\Josh1\OneDrive\Documents\Unity\2022.1.23f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Users\Josh1\OneDrive\Documents\Unity\2022.1.23f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

```
stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Josh1\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

Been searching for 2hrs how to fix this nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Do you have a keystore file at this location `C:\Users\Josh1\.android\debug.keystore`?

Comment: Hey i do yea i downgraded to unity 2021 and still having the same issue

Comment: Well, either the keystore you have is corrupt or you're using the wrong password/alias for it.

Comment: Okay thank you, ill be honest i dont even know what a keystore is haha

Comment: Sorted now thank you! Anyonr else havin the problem i just created a new key in the keystore manager and saved it in the game file it worked a charm

Comment: The "debug.keystore" it's generated automatically for any android application, but for Unity you should create a new keystore through the keystore manager.